# Why does clicking a checkbox widen HTML div's in google chrome 51 (flexbox)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Edit:  I fixed this by updating to the latest version of Chrome (v53)

I am creating an HTML container which will contain an unknown number of selection elements - check boxes, drop downs, and selection lists.  I am planning to use a flexbox as the container to hold all of these elements.

I am trying to put together the HTML/css for this, but I'm noticing a weird behavior - when I check or uncheck the checkbox, some of my divs get wider and wider.  This does not happen in firefox or internet explorer.

[here's an example of the code in action](https://jsfiddle.net/dqjmacu9/)

[here's an example of what I see when I save the below HTML to my computer, and open it in chrome v51](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOdqO.gif)

[here's an example of what I see when I open the jsfiddle in chrome v51](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxO6O.gif)

Here's the HTML/css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        body {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }
        div {            
            margin:5px;
            padding:2px;
        }

        .div1 {
            display:flex;
            flex-wrap:wrap;
            flex-direction:column;
            border:solid;
            border-color:black;
            position:absolute;
            top:20vh;
            left:20vw;
            height:60vh;
            width:60vw;
            overflow-y:no-display;
            overflow-x:auto;
            align-items:stretch;
        }

        .diva, .divb, .divc {
            overflow-x:auto;
            overflow-y:auto;
            min-width:1in;
            max-height:2in;
            max-width:2in;
        }

        .diva {
            border:solid;
            border-color:blue;
        }
        .divb {
            border:solid;
            border-color:red;
        }
        .divc {
            border:solid;
            border-color:green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div1">
        <div class="diva">
            div a
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="checkboxa">checkbox A</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxa" name="checkboxa" />
        </div>
        <div class="diva">
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            div a
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
        </div>
        <div class="divb">
            div b long long long long long long content
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
        </div>
        <div class="diva">
            div a
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
        </div>
        <div class="divc">
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            div c  long long long long long long content
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>
        <div class="divb">
            div b
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
        </div>
        <div class="diva">
            div a
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
        </div>
        <div class="diva">
            div a
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
        </div>
        <div class="divc">
            div c long long long long long long content
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
        </div>
        <div class="divb">
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            div b
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
        </div>
        <div class="diva">
            div a
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
        </div>
        <div class="diva">
            div a
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            tall content
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
}
.div1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: solid;
  border-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20vh;
  left: 20vw;
  height: 60vh;
  width: 60vw;
  overflow-y: no-display;
  overflow-x: auto;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.diva,
.divb,
.divc {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-width: 1in;
  max-height: 2in;
  max-width: 2in;
}
.diva {
  border: solid;
  border-color: blue;
}
.divb {
  border: solid;
  border-color: red;
}
.divc {
  border: solid;
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="diva">
    div a
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="checkboxa">checkbox A</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxa" name="checkboxa" />
  </div>
  <div class="diva">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />div a
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
  </div>
  <div class="divb">
    div b long long long long long long content
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
  </div>
  <div class="diva">
    div a
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
  </div>
  <div class="divc">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />div c long long long long long long content
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>
  <div class="divb">
    div b
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
  </div>
  <div class="diva">
    div a
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
  </div>
  <div class="diva">
    div a
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
  </div>
  <div class="divc">
    div c long long long long long long content
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
  </div>
  <div class="divb">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />div b
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
  </div>
  <div class="diva">
    div a
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
  </div>
  <div class="diva">
    div a
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />tall content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using Chrome v53 and I'm unable to see any problem on the JSFiddle link you've provided. Perhaps this was something they've already fixed?

Comment: Which Browser are showing that behaviour? What version do they have?

Comment: not happened for me

Comment: I added some gifs of what I see when I run this in Chrome v51.  I'll try downloading v53 and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to version 53 of google chrome fixed this issue.